# Everything after "&" is lost when sent through jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Everything that I type after "&" in the input text box is lost when sent through jQuery AJAX.

For example, If I type

```
Line 1    
Line 2
```

Then there is no any problem with the content.

It gets the content from page and via AJAX as

```
<p>Line 1</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
```

But If I enter content as (look at the empty line between Line 1 and Line 2):

```
Line 1

Line 2
```

Then on page I get the following content in alert box

```
<p>Line 1</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
```

But the server gets following content

```
<p>Line 1</p>
<p
```

Clearly, the remaining content after `<p>Line 1</p>` has been truncated.

What is the solution to fix this issue?

**EDIT**

The code which sends data to the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnsave").click(function(){
        var textarea_val = $("#mytextarea").val();
        //alert(textarea_val);

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/save-content.php",
            data: "comment="+textarea_val,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP code which receives data:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['btnsave']))
{
    $comment = $_GET['mytextarea'];

    echo $comment;
}
?>
```

Comment: And you did not show the most important part.... the code that submits to the server!

Comment: @epascarello Please find my updated portion with code you wanted to see.

Answer (score 2):

There are some characters which have special meaning. Some such characters are +, %, & etc. '+' character is interpreted as a space on the server side. When used in form fields it is replaced by spaces. When sending the ajax request, you can easily see '+' replaced with a space in the browser console.

Similarly '&' character is treated as a separator between parameters. So if you type "sachin&1" in the text box then the value sent to the server will be "sachin" as the server will assume that it has received two parameters, "uname" and "1" with the value of "uname" as "sachin" and value of "1" as null.

**Solution**

In order to send special symbols such as +, %, & etc., to the server, they need to be encoded. Javascript provides a method `encodeURIComponent()` which encodes all special characters present in the string passed to it. So in the above ajax request, if the "uname" parameter is sent as

```
data: "uname=" + encodeURIComponent($("#userName").val())
```

then if the user types in "sachin+1", the value received at the server will be the same, that is, '+' will not be removed.